# If statement only executing "one" if

Tags: java

```
private void updateGame() {
    // Is the game won (or lost)?
    // Put here code to end the game (= no more aliens)
    this.window.suspendRepaints(); // to speed up the drawing
    // Update the ArrayList (remove the dead aliens)
    Iterator<Alien> it = aliens.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Alien a = it.next();
        if (a.isDead()) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
    // Level 1



    // Move the aliens
    for (Alien a : aliens) {
        a.move();
    }

    // Move the space ship
    this.spaceShip.move();

    // Display it all
    this.window.resumeRepaints();


if (aliens.isEmpty() && counter==0) {
    counter++;
    this.aliens = new ArrayList<Alien>();
    System.out.println(counter);
    int z1 = 3 * SpaceShip.WIDTH;
    int x1 = 3 * SpaceShip.WIDTH;
    int y1 = 5 * Alien.RADIUS;


    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        if (i > 12){
            this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window, new Point (z1,y1+20)));
            x1+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;
        }else{
            this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window,new Point (x1,y1)));
            x1+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;

        }
    }
}


    else if(aliens.isEmpty() && counter==1) {
        counter++;
    this.aliens = new ArrayList<Alien>();
    System.out.println(counter);
    int z2 = 3 * SpaceShip.WIDTH;
    int x2 = 3 * SpaceShip.WIDTH;
    int y2 = 5 * Alien.RADIUS;

    for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
        if (i > 12){
            this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window, new Point (z2,y2+20)));
            x2+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;
        }else{
            this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window,new Point (x2,y2)));
            x2+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;

        }
    }
}

    else if (aliens.isEmpty() && counter==2) {
    counter++;
    this.aliens = new ArrayList<Alien>();
    System.out.println(counter);
    int z3 = 3 * SpaceShip.WIDTH;
    int x3 = 3 * SpaceShip.WIDTH;
    int y3 = 5 * Alien.RADIUS;
    for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
        if (i > 12){
            this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window, new Point (z3,y3+20)));
            x3+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;
        }else{
            this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window,new Point (x3,y3)));
            x3+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;

        }
    }
}
}
```

I just don't get why it's not using anything but the first if statement. My count is going up (I can tell by printing it to the console). But for some reason, it doesn't execute any of the other if statements. Counter is defined in the public class SpaceInvader with a start of 0 at the count. Is the problem because the updateGame method a void method? I don't believe so since it is updating my counter outside of that method, but I could be wrong? Ahead of time, I am sorry, I am new to programming.

Comment: How do you know it only executes the first one?

Comment: Also, which one is the first one? (Is it the part starting with `if (aliens.isEmpty() && counter==0) {`?)

Comment: Btw, I'm creating my own Space invader game! :) I need to replenish the aliens after the array list gets emptied (player kills all aliens). Each time the array list is emptied, I want to create more and more aliens, hence the reason that I am using these if statements.

Comment: Yes, it's the counter==0 one. I have a default alien ArrayList when the array is first created and the game is started up. It shows up with 12 aliens. After that, it goes to the counter==0 if statement I created, which then creates 14 aliens. After that though, it just keeps creating 14 aliens when the ArrayList is cleared.

Comment: Where is counter defined?  I'm assuming that something external to this function is resetting counter to 0.

Comment: Counter is defined in the public class SpaceInvader with a start of 0 at the count.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: So the constructor for the class sets counter to 0?  Are you instantiating this class in a loop then? I can't see any reason other than the counter being somehow reset for the other if statements to not execute.  I'm assuming you have a main event loop which calls this function, does it do a new SpaceInvader() or something? Post where this function is called, please.

Comment: Also, debugger, yes.

Comment: Alas I knew the day would come that I would need to learn the debugger. I don't know how to use it, but I suppose Youtube can remedy that.

Comment: In regards to the 'if' statement that is not running (but should be), are you referring to the one nested within the 'for' loop? Which 'if' statement are you referring to?

Comment: I didn't use the debugger sadly. I figured out that I was using the same x variable for all of my ArrayLists, so it was popping up with the same ArrayList every time. I don't really understand how that works out, but I fixed it by naming the variables properly like I was intending to, I just forgot to do so. <code> this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window, new Point (z2,y2+20)));
            x2+= 5* Alien.RADIUS; </code>

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use the debugger sadly. I figured out that I was using the same x variable for all of my ArrayLists, so it was popping up with the same ArrayList every time. I don't really understand how that works out, but I fixed it by naming the variables properly like I was intending to, I just forgot to do so.

```
this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window, new Point (z2,y2+20)));
        x2+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;
```

should be

```
this.aliens.add(new Alien(this.window, new Point (z2,y2+20)));
        z2+= 5* Alien.RADIUS;
```

the difference is in my variable z2 vs x2, which I was using x2 for every new ArrayList addition, which messed up the ArrayList. All peachy now!